# How to write this signature?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a homework assignment that wants me to

> Please define 1 private member function (helper) called `Display`, that takes as an argument the array containing the object to display and the index of that object in the array.

I believe it wants me to make a private member function and pass two arguments to it, one an array or vector(?) (the class is working on vectors), and the other an int for the index?

So I'm guessing something like:

```
void Display(vector<Object> vector, int index);
```

What is the correct signature?

Comment: As I understand this task you have to take an array, not a vector... Even though this is not a question so...

Comment: Your guess for the function signature is correct, other than LPK's comment... I don't think this is a very good question, though.

Comment: You essentially repeated what it said so, sounds like you got it.

Comment: the question clearly says array, so just like you thought but with an array

Comment: @JacobRitchie What?! "...that takes as an argument the array containing the object..."

Comment: To recap: a C++ vector declaration looks like `std::vector<int> vector`. A C-style array declaration looks like `int a[10]`.

A vector can change size dynamically. An array has fixed size.

Comment: @LPK - I meant he's right, other than getting the data structure wrong, as you pointed out.

Comment: +1 To be fair to the OP, while this was homework, he still showed his work and what he thought was the answer. He's not just blindly spitting out a question. It's a decent beginner question.

Comment: Strictly speaking, C++ (like C) does not have parameters of array type. If you want to achieve the effect of passing an array (and you don't want to use `std::vector` or something similar), the convention is to pass a pointer to the array's initial element. The language syntax lets you do this in a way that makes it *appear* that you're passing an array, but for example the length of the array is not passed.

Comment: Wow yall answer fast
so I guess I would use void Display(Object array[maxPerBuildingType], int index);

*maxPerBuildingType is a static const int = to 7

I'm not sure if I should use "Object" or any other identifier. Also Object seem to be undefined in c++ unlike Java :/

Comment: As per @keith-thompson's answer, you should replace `Object array[maxPerBuildingType]` with `Object array[]` (or `Object * array`). You put the `maxPerBuildingType` parameter when you declare the array, not when you declare the function that you pass the array to. The same function can accept an array of any size.

Comment: @JacobRitchie: Right. It's a misfeature of both C and C++ that in a declaration like `void func(int array[42]);`, the `42` is silently ignored (because a parameter defined with array syntax is really a pointer, as if you has written `void func(int *array);`). This rule applies *only* to parameters, not to variable declarations.

Comment: Ahh okay is there a library for Object, it's not allowing me to use it and passing an error

Answer (score 0):

That is an unclear question so you got one thing right. I presume as others have pointed out your teacher is looking for a signature using an array not a vector. It would look more like this :

```
void Display(DisplayableObject* array, const int& objectIndex);
```

I would note however that it would be better to just pass the object directly like this :

```
void Display(const DisplayableObject& object); //if it can be const
```

You also may have access violation if the objectIndex is out of bound.

Plus passing an array as a pointer is more of a C-Style way to do things rather than a C++ way.

I am curious as to what the pedagogy goal is here.

Comment: Hmm the wording is very confusing and I've been bashing my head in all last night trying to figure it out. The professor said that it's stated as clearly as possible and won't give the answer for it. 
Assignment: https://elearning.uh.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-2625849-dt-content-rid-18333852_1/courses/H_20161_COSC_1320_27116/COSC1320PA02_Spring2016.pdf

Comment: The assignment requires login information to view, so it's probably not meant to be distributed to people not in the course.

Comment: yeh well that sucks I'm just stuck on this one part, does DisplayableObjectArray or Displayable need a library to use im getting the unidentiable error

Comment: It is just an exemple, you actually need to write a class for the object to be displayed. You could call it DisplayableObject or something, or you could display an int I suppose. It depends what needs to be displayed.

Comment: Considering how the question is worded, `template<size_t N> void Display(const DisplayableObject (&arr)[N], int index)` might also be a valid signature.